# sonar exception -- Unknown database status: FRESH_INSTALL

Tags: exception, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am getting the following error when running sonar-runner-2.3 (with sonar-3.7). Any help is greatly appreciated. I have double checked the database configuration in both the sonar server and sonar runner and it looks good. Also, searching for similar errors on stackoverflow hasn't helped.

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:90)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:41)
Caused by: org.sonar.core.persistence.BadDatabaseVersion: Unknown database status: FRESH_INSTALL
```

Comment: Can you update your question to specify: which command you are running for the analysis? can you access the Web interface? do you get anything in the server logs? ("conf/sonar.log")

Comment: Hi, I am trying to run sonar-runner (analysis step). I don't see anything more in the logs (apart from what I have included in the post above). Thanks!

Comment: Any specific parameters passed to the sonar-runner command? The log you've posted is on batch side, I was asking for the log on server side. And can you access the Web interface? I'm asking all those questions because SonarQube should never be in "FRESH_INSTALL" state.

Comment: I am not passing any arguments to the "sonar-runner" command. I can access the web interface. I have checked the server side logs (sonar-3.7/logs/sonar.log) and don't see any errors there.